# escaping curly braces in jquery templates and knockout js

Tags: jquery-templates, knockout.js

I have a jquery template in which I have knockout js binding to a function literal, the function literal has curly braces inside and they are been wrongly interpreted by the template engine, here is the template:

```
<button {{html "data-bind='click: function(){ loadProduct(" + i + ") }'" }}>${ product.Name }</button>
```

Is there any way to scape those braces? I've tried the {#literal} tag without success, also I wrapped everying in the {{ html }} tag because the hyphen in "data-bind" is also wrongly interpreted by the engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add data-bind attributes in your jQuery template, then it is not necessary to do so much escaping.

I am assuming that "i" in your case is from looping through your products using something like  {{each(i, product) Products}}.  In your template, you can define this element like:

```
<button data-bind="click: function(){ loadProduct(i); }">${product.Name}</button>
```

It will have access to the variable "i" in the function without concatenating strings.

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/Pq5Vd/

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had been stucked with this for some time already, really, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that's the problem? jQuery templates should only recognize double curly brackets. Single curly should work fine like here > http://jsfiddle.net/neebz/9fsv2/